# postgresql select statement result into a hash

Tags: ruby, select, hash

I have a simple sql select statement with just 2 selected columns. I'd like to get the result into a simple hash.

```
results = db_conn.exec("SELECT hostname, ipv FROM clients")
```

I'd like the hash to look something like this:

```
"computer1"=>"192.168.0.1"
"computer2"=>"192.168.0.2"
"computer3"=>"192.168.0.3"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what is the type of the `result` variable? Can you show a sample?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is for specific case only, but for instance if you are using the `pg` gem to run the query you will get a `PG::Result` object which has some utility methods for playing around with the actual data returned from the query.

Now what you can do after you've run your query

```
results = db_conn.exec("SELECT hostname, ipv FROM clients")
```

Since you are selecting only two columns running the [values](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Result.html#method-i-values) method on `results` will return you a two dimensional array.

```
[
  ["computer1", "192.168.0.1"],
  ["computer2", "192.168.0.2"],
  ["computer3", "192.168.0.3"],
]
```

So in that case to get the wanted result

```
"computer1"=>"192.168.0.1"
"computer2"=>"192.168.0.2"
"computer3"=>"192.168.0.3"
```

You can reuse the [::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method on `Hash`. So the final statement will be something like

```
Hash[db_conn.exec("SELECT hostname, ipv FROM clients").values]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'pg'

conn = PGconn.open(
  :dbname => 'mytestdb',
  :user => 'postgres',
  :password => '',
)
result_set  = conn.exec("SELECT hostname, ipv FROM clients")

my_results = {}

result_set.each do |row|
  my_results[row['hostname']] = row['ipv']
end

p my_results

--output:--
{"computer1"=>"172.16.254.1", "computer2"=>"172.16.254.2"}
```

Comment: people use to get hands in SQL for perfomance improvement. There's no point in using SQL and then using map since it will iterate over the entire array, making the process very slow.